# MockMvc and Spring Security - Null FilterChainProxy

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, spring-security

I need to test my REST Controllers which they are secured using Spring Security. I'm using MockMvc as spring security reference suggests here

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc

Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LikesTest {

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                //.standaloneSetup(new MessageController())
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser("user")
    public void testAddLike() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/like?msgId=4&like=false"));
    }
}
```

When i'm running the JUnit test, i'm getting this failure trace

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:223)

Also if remove the bean inside applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"/>
```

Then i'm getting this failure trace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be
>   null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain
>   implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.   at
>   org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.beforeMockMvcCreated(SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.java:62)

I have no idea why the FilterChainProxy is null. Inside my Web.xml i have declare the DelegatingFilterProxy with filter-name springSecurityFilterChain and my application works fine. Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score -19, accepted):

I've managed to get it working. 
Just make sure you have the correct Context Configurations. Also you don't need to declare a FilterChainProxy bean.
Thanks

Comment: >>> Just make sure you have the correct Context Configurations. If people know how their configurations should look, then they would not come to this post.

Comment: Wouldnt it be nice to give some more details than 'Just make sure you have the correct Context Configurations' which is an answer that can be applied to probably all spring related questions, without giving the reader the slightest clue about the real solution...

Comment: your answer is useless unless you put the context.xml here

Answer (score 6):

In your case, when using `.webAppContextSetup` you probably forgot to extend `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` to make security filters initialized.

With standalone setup one would need to add her security config to @ContextConfiguration and autowire this bean:

```
 @Autowired
 FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
```

Then prepare MockMvc like this:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
   .standaloneSetup(controller)
   .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
   .build();
```

Comment: FilterChainProxy is not a bean,